# If I'm your representative, you are my ______?

Tags: single-word-requests

So, Dorian has a representative: John. Then John has a _______: Dorian.

(Dorian elected John / Dorian chose John / Dorian picked John / Dorian marked John as his representative / ...)

Comment: Can you reword this in complex sentences. As is, it is not clear what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @rhetorician Avoid answers in comments. We get it: standards for comments are low, they get an undeserved privileged position on the page above answers, and they cannot be community edited or peer reviewed. But this discourages people from posting actual answers and defeats the core answer ranking process. A better place to post an answer is in the answer box. See: [Privileges > Comment Everywhere – Help Center](https://chat.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). See also: [Is SE enforcing “no answers in comments”? – Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10646/)

Comment: As the answers below show, the term 'representative' really needs restricting to a certain sense before a definitive answer may be attempted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of politics, one possibility is:

**constituent**

See:

[Merriam-Webster Online](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/constituent)

*"one who authorizes another to act as agent"*

Comment: Thanks, now I have representative and constituents, perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Gary'sStudent's answer is true for a government representative.  In a business or a law context, John would have a **client.**

Comment: I have no idea where the down vote came from, but just to be clear for future visitors: if I hire a lawyer, they become my representative and I become their client. Lawyers don't have constituents.

Comment: It happens all the time. :) +1